# String array throws OutOfMemoryException for large multi-line entries

Tags: c#, winforms, string, out-of-memory

In a Windows Forms C# app, I have a textbox where users paste log data, and it sorts it. I need to check each line individualy so I split the input by the new line, but if there are a lot of lines, greater than 100,000 or so, it throws a OutOfMemoryException.

My code looks like this:

```
StringSplitOptions splitOptions = new StringSplitOptions();
if(removeEmptyLines_CB.Checked)
    splitOptions = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;
else
    splitOptions = StringSplitOptions.None;

List<string> outputLines = new List<string>();

foreach(string line in input_TB.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, splitOptions))
{
    if(line.Contains(inputCompare_TB.Text))
        outputLines.Add(line);
}
output_TB.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, outputLines);
```

The problem comes from when I split the textbox text by line, here `input_TB.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }`

Is there a better way to do this? I've thought about taking the first X amount of text, truncating at a new line and repeat until everything has been read, but this seems tedious. Or is there a way to allocate more memory for it?

Thanks,
Garrett

**Update**

Thanks to Attila, I came up with this and it seems to work. Thanks

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(input_TB.Text);
string line;
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if(line.Contains(inputCompare_TB.Text))
        outputLines.Add(line);
}
output_TB.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, outputLines);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to do this would be to extract and process one line at a time, and use a `StringBuilder` to create the result:

```
StringBuilder outputTxt = new StringBuilder();
string txt = input_TB.Text;
int txtIndex = 0;
while (txtIndex < txt.Length) {
  int startLineIndex = txtIndex;
GetMore:
  while (txtIndex < txt.Length && txt[txtIndex] != '\r'  && txt[txtIndex] != '\n')) {
    txtIndex++;
  }
  if (txtIndex < txt.Length && txt[txtIndex] == '\r' && (txtIndex == txt.Length-1 || txt[txtIndex+1] != '\n') {
    txtIndex++;
    goto GetMore; 
  }
  string line = txt.Substring(startLineIndex, txtIndex-startLineIndex);
  if (line.Contains(inputCompare_TB.Text)) {
    if (outputTxt.Length > 0)
      outputTxt.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    outputTxt.Append(line); 
  }
  txtIndex++;
} 
output_TB.Text = outputTxt.ToString();
```

Pre-emptive comment: someone will object to the `goto` - but it is what's needed here, the alternatives are much more complex (reg exp for example), or fake the goto with another loop and `continue` or `break`

Using a `StringReader` to split the lines is a much cleaner solution<strike>, but it does not handle both `\r\n` and `\n` as a new line</strike>:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(input_TB.Text); 
StringBuilder outputTxt = new StringBuilder();
string compareTxt = inputCompare_TB.Text;
string line; 
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) { 
  if (line.Contains(compareTxt)) {
    if (outputTxt.Length > 0)
      outputTxt.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    outputTxt.Append(line); 
  }
} 
output_TB.Text = outputTxt.ToString();
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could use a goto statement in c#, don't think I've used one since I was a kid playing around with pascal and basic, interesting. This seems overly complicated though, take a look at my update to my question.

Comment: I added a note at the end of my answer - your update is cleaner but does not handle both `\r\n` and `\n` as end lines. If you can do away with that it is fine - I still suggest to use a `StringBuilder`, avoiding to create a (big?) intermediate list of strings.

Comment: Yes, `goto` are possible in C#, and I use them - sparingly - as in this case.

Comment: StringReader handles \r, \n or \r\n as a newline character.

Comment: In my update code, does 'while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)' create a bunch of strings or does it just keep re-using the same one?

Comment: It creates a new string each time, but the old ones won't be referenced anymore and so the garbage collector will re-use their memory

Answer (score 3):

`Split` will have to duplicate the memory need of the original text, plus overhead of `string` objects for each line.  If this causes memory issues, a reliable way of processing the input is to parse one line at a time.

Comment: Thanks, take a look at my update and let me know if that is what you meant. I will mark this as answered soon, I just want to see a couple other ideas. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way to do this on large text files is to open the file manually and use a `StreamReader`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext.aspx) is an example how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid creating strings for all lines and the array by creating the string for each line one at a time:

```
var eol = new[] { '\r', '\n' };

var pos = 0;
while (pos < input.Length)
{
    var i = input.IndexOfAny(eol, pos);
    if (i < 0)
    {
        i = input.Length;
    }
    if (i != pos)
    {
        var line = input.Substring(pos, i - pos);

        // process line
    }
    pos = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On other hand, [In this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363680/505729) say that the point is that "split" method is implemented poorly. Read it, and make your conclusions.

Like Attila said, you have to parse line by line.