# All Enum items to string (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, enums

How to convert all elements from enum to string?

Assume I have:

```
public enum LogicOperands {
        None,
        Or,
        And,
        Custom
}
```

And what I want to archive is something like:

```
string LogicOperandsStr = LogicOperands.ToString();
// expected result:  "None,Or,And,Custom"
```

Comment: Checking this answer may useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12022617/1830909

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
string s = string.Join(",",Enum.GetNames(typeof(LogicOperands)));
```

Answer (score 14):

You have to do something like this:

```
var sbItems = new StringBuilder()
foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(LogicOperands)))
{
    if(sbItems.Length>0)
        sbItems.Append(',');
    sbItems.Append(item);
}
```

Or in Linq:

```
var list = Enum.GetNames(typeof(LogicOperands)).Aggregate((x,y) => x + "," + y);
```

Comment: I was thinking of the similar linq version, you beat me. +1

Comment: Please don't abuse StringBuilder like that!

Comment: Randolpho what's wrong with the stringbuilder code ? What abuse ?

Comment: Indeed, it looks okay to me. Using String.Join is neater, but I don't see any "abuse" here.

Comment: Unless you've got dozens of items in the enumeration, you're better off with a string concatenation.

Comment: Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529999/when-to-use-string-builder/530007

Comment: Wait... didn't you write the correct answer to that Jon? This is a trivial loop. StringBuilder is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

```
string LogicOperandsStr 
     = Enum.GetNames(typeof(LogicOoperands)).Aggregate((current, next)=> 
                                                       current + "," + next);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @Moose's answer is the best, I suggest you cache the value, since you might be using it frequently, but it's 100% unlikely to change during execution -- unless you're modifying and re-compiling the enum. :)

Like so:

```
public static class LogicOperandsHelper
{
  public static readonly string OperandList = 
    string.Join(",", Enum.GetNames(typeof(LogicOperands)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string value in Enum.GetNames(typeof(LogicOoperands))
{
    str = str + "," + value;
}
```

Comment: You have to trim last comma

Answer (score 0):

A simple and generic way to convert a enum to something you can interact:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> ToList<T>() where T : struct
{
   return ((IEnumerable<T>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))).ToDictionary(item => Convert.ToInt32(item), item => item.ToString());
}
```

and then:

```
var enums = EnumHelper.ToList<MyEnum>();
```