# Get a List<string> of my enum attributes with a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, enums, custom-attributes

At start, we have this basic enum.

```
public enum E_Levels {

    [ValueOfEnum("Low level")]
    LOW,

    [ValueOfEnum("Normal level")]
    NORMAL,

    [ValueOfEnum("High level")]
    HIGH
}
```

And I would like to get a `List<string>` **whatever the enum**. Something like `Extensions.GetValuesOfEnum<E_Levels>()` which could return a `List<string>` with "Low level", "Normal level" and "High level" in it.

StackOF helped me to get **one** value attribute :

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static string ToValueOfEnum(this Enum value) {

        FieldInfo fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        ValueOfEnum[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValueOfEnum), false) as ValueOfEnum[];
        return attribs.Length > 0 ? attribs[0].value : null;
    }
}
```

And I can call this method whatever the enum : `E_Levels.LOW.ToValueOfEnum()`.

Furthermore, StackOF helped me to get a `List<string>` for a **specific** enum.
I made this method in a controller :

```
private List<string> GetLevels() {

List<string> levelsToReturn = new List<string>();
var levels = Enum.GetValues(typeof(E_Levels)).Cast<E_Levels>();
foreach(E_Levels l in levels) 
    levelsToReturn.Add(l.ToValueOfEnum());

return levelsToReturn;
}
```

But this way requires me to rewrite the same method for each enum.
So I tried to add this generic method my class Extensions :

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static string ToValueOfEnum(this Enum value) {...}

    public static List<string> GetValuesOf<T>() {

        List<string> levelsToReturn = new List<string>();
        var levels = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
        foreach(T l in levels) 
        levelsToReturn.Add(l.ToValueOfEnum());

        return levelsToReturn;
    }
}
```

But in my foreach, `.ToValueOfEnum()` is an unknown method.
So I am in trouble, I hoped I could find a way to not rewrite again and again the same method for each enum...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's try to keep this more general purpose.

I have an [extension method](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5354/3860) that could grab attributes off of enum values.  This would give you quick access to the attributes.

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum value)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
        return type.GetField(name)
            .GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .OfType<TAttribute>()
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Using this, you could create some queries to get what you want.

```
var valuesOfLevels =
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(E_Levels)).Cast<E_Levels>()
        .Select(level => level.GetAttribute<ValueOfEnumAttribute>().Value);
```

So your `GetValuesOf()` method (which is not a great name for such a specialty method IMHO) can be written like this:

```
public static List<string> GetValuesOf<TEnum>()
    where TEnum : struct // can't constrain to enums so closest thing
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<Enum>()
               .Select(val => val.GetAttribute<ValueOfEnumAttribute>().Value)
               .ToList();
}
```

Now you may call the method like so:

```
var levelValues = GetValueOf<E_Levels>();
// levelValues = { "Low level", "Normal level", "High level" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeff, this is what I was looking for. `Select()` replaces my foreach and your `GetAttribute<>()` method is the icing on the cake. I'll just switch your `GetCustomAttributes()` to the `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute()` from @GSerjo. And you were right: `GetValuesOf` was not a relevant name...

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

You might try casting `(Enum)(object)l`, changing `ToValueOfEnum` to take an `object`, or just inline the method:

```
public static List<string> GetValuesOf<T>()
{

    List<string> levelsToReturn = new List<string>();
    var levels = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
    foreach (T value in levels)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        ValueOfEnum[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValueOfEnum), false) as ValueOfEnum[];
        levelsToReturn.Add(attribs.Length > 0 ? attribs[0].value : null);
    }

    return levelsToReturn;
}
```

Here's a one-line solution using the casting approach:

```
return new List<string>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<Enum>().Select(x => x.ToValueOfEnum()));
```

In case you weren't clear on why `T` wasn't recognized as an `Enum` like `E_Levels` is, that's because you didn't specify that `T : enum`.  Unfortunately, you can't specify that in C# (even though the CLR supports it), so other approaches like runtime checking/assuming (such as what I'm suggesting here) or post-compile code modifications (e.g. [unconstrained-melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/)) have to be done.

Comment: I guess that the one-line solution is cleaner than explicit the loop with a foreach. And I understand now why I couldn't use my enum method...

Answer (score 0):

.Net already has the same attribute `Description` so you can use this one instead `ValueOfEnum`.

What about `dynamic` and extension on `type` and following example

```
[TestFixture]
public sealed class ForTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var values = typeof(Levels).ToValues();
        values.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static List<string> ToValues(this Type value)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var values = ToConcreteValues(value);
        foreach (dynamic item in values)
        {
            Description attribute = GetAttribute<Description>(item);
            result.Add(attribute.Description);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static dynamic ToConcreteValues(Type enumType)
    {
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        Type list = typeof (List<>);
        Type resultType = list.MakeGenericType(enumType);
        dynamic result = Activator.CreateInstance(resultType);
        foreach (object value in values)
        {
            dynamic concreteValue = Enum.Parse(enumType, value.ToString());
            result.Add(concreteValue);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(dynamic value)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(Enum.GetName(type, value));
        return (TAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, typeof (TAttribute));
    }
}

public enum Levels
{
    [Description("Low level")]LOW,
    [Description("Normal level")] NORMAL,
    [Description("High level")] HIGH
}
```

result output:

```
Low level
Normal level
High level
```

Comment: I ignored that `Description` was already in .NET, I thought people used it as a custom attribute. 
Concerning your approach, i find it interesting. I sealed my custom attribute. But what are advantages to use `dynamic` type ? I heard the `dynamic` was not a safe type cuz the compiler does nothing to check if methods you call exist or not.

Comment: Only one, you can create extension on any enum thru type and yes, dynamic can be checked only in runtime.

Comment: Hmm... but @JeffMercado propose a similar way without `dynamic` right ? (you just get your `List<string>` like this : `GetValueOf<E_Levels>()`) Or your solution has another gain ?

Comment: almost, all solutions are ugly, all versions can be checked only in runtime. Version thru *GetValueOf<E_Levels>* will work quickly then thru `dinamic`