# Get list all of Category Attribute in enum?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, reflection, enums

I have an enum as below:

```
public enum DatabaseCommand
{
     [Category("Connection")]
     Connected= 0,
     [Category("Connection")]
     Disconnected,
     [Category("Connection")]
     GetConnectionStatus,
     [Category("Execute")]
     ExecuteSQLString,
     [Category("Execute")]
     ExecuteSQLStoreProcedure,
     CustomCommand,
}
```

So, how can I list all of Category Attribute by passing `typeof(DatabaseCommand)` and return a array of string as below:

```
"Connection" , "Execute" and "".
```

Any help?
Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022557/get-a-liststring-of-my-enum-attributes-with-a-generic-method

Comment: Not the same, but take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value

Comment: Thank you all, I had modified some code and it work for me.