# Enum to list as an extension?

Tags: c#

I have various enums that I use as sources for dropdown lists, In order to provide for a user-friendly description, I added a `Description` attribute to each enum, and then do the following:

```
var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
               .Cast<MyEnum>()
               .ToDictionary(k => k, v => v.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)
               .ToList();
```

The above is repetitive because I have to use it in a lot of places. I tried to add an extension method:

```
    public static T GetAttributeOfType<T>(this Enum enumVal) where T : System.Attribute
    {
        var type = enumVal.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
        var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);

        return (attributes.Length > 0) ? (T)attributes[0] : null;
    }

    public static KeyValuePair<T, string> ToList<T>(this Enum source) 
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
                   .Cast<T>()
                   .ToDictionary(k => k, v => v.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)
                   .ToList();
    }
```

However, I get an exception:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not a delegate type

What is the correct way to use it as an extension (using the above 2 methods)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Enum.GetValues(typeof(source))?

Comment: @Kevin If I do that I get an exception: The type of namespace name 'source' could not be found.

Comment: The second method (`ToList`) is strange. First, it doesn't compile. Second, the return type is unclear - you pass a single `Enum` value, then use `ToDictionary(..).ToList()` which is making a list, and the return type is single `KeyValuePair`. So what should it really be - single value or list? If it is a list, then it would be strange to be extension method, so you'll have to pass an enum value to get the list, like `MyEnum.A.ToList<MyEnum>()`. Shortly, are you seeking for an equivalent of the repetitive code at the beginning of the post?

Comment: Checking this answer may useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12022617/1830909

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the correct way to use it as an extension (using the above 2 methods)?

There is no correct way to use it as an **extension**. Extension methods (similar to instance methods) are used when you have a **value** (instance) and for instance want to get some information related to that value. So the extension method would make sense if you want to get the description of a single `enum` value.

However, in your case the information you need (the list of `enum` value/description pairs) is not tied to a specific `enum` value, but to the `enum` **type**. Which means you just need a plain **static** generic method similar to [`Enum.TryParse<TEnum>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx). Ideally you would constrain the generic argument to allow only `enum`, but this type of constraint is not supported (yet), so we'll use (similar to the above system method) just `where TEnum : struct` and will add runtime check.

So here is a sample implementation:

```
public static class EnumInfo
{
    public static List<KeyValuePair<TEnum, string>> GetList<TEnum>()
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return ((TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
           .ToDictionary(k => k, v => ((Enum)(object)v).GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)
           .ToList();
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Foo")]
    A,
    [Description("Bar")]
    B,
    [Description("Baz")]
    C,
}

var list = EnumInfo.GetList<MyEnum>();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this extension method in my stack and use it for the same thing all the time.

```
public static string Description(this Enum @enum)
{
    try
    {
        var @string = @enum.ToString();

        var attribute =
            @enum.GetType()
                 .GetField(@string)
                 .GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>(false);

        return attribute != null ? attribute.Description : @string;
    }
    catch // Log nothing, just return an empty string
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
MyEnum.Value.Description(); // The value from within the description attr.
```

Additionally, you can use this one to get a IDictionary for binding purposes.

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException("'enumValue' is not an Enumeration!");
    }

    var names = Enum.GetNames(type);
    var values = Enum.GetValues(type);

    return Enumerable.Range(0, names.Length)
                     .Select(index => new
                     {
                         Key = names[index],
                         Value = ((Enum)values.GetValue(index)).Description()
                     })
                     .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value);
}
```

Use it like so:

```
var dictionary = typeof(MyEnum).ToDictionary();
```

**Update**

Here is a working [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jy9Cfc).

```
public static Dictionary<TEnum, string> ToDictionary<TEnum>(this Type type)
    where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    return Enum.GetValues(type)
               .OfType<TEnum>()
               .ToDictionary(value => value, value => value.Description());
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public enum Test
{
    [Description("A test enum value for 'Foo'")]
    Foo,
    [Description("A test enum value for 'Bar'")]
    Bar
}

typeof(Test).ToDictionary<Test>()
```

Comment: Doesn't this method return the string of just one enum?

Comment: You'd want to call the ToDictionary() extension method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic method which would take `Enum` and `Attribute` as generic argument.

For getting any attribute, you can create an extension method like:

```
public static string AttributeValue<TEnum,TAttribute>(this TEnum value,Func<TAttribute,string> func) where T : Attribute
{
   FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

   T attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(T)) as T;

   return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : func(attribute);

}
```

and here is the method for converting it to dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<TEnum,string> ToDictionary<TEnum,TAttribute>(this TEnum obj,Func<TAttribute,string> func)
  where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
  where TAttribute : Attribute
    {

        return (Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<TEnum>()
            .Select(x =>
                new
                {
                    Value = x,
                    Description = x.AttributeValue<TEnum,TAttribute>(func)
                }).ToDictionary(x=>x.Value,x=>x.Description));



    }
```

You can call it this way:

```
 var test =  eUserRole.SuperAdmin
                      .ToDictionary<eUserRole,EnumDisplayNameAttribute>(attr=>attr.DisplayName);
```

I have used this Enum and Attribute as example:

```
public class EnumDisplayNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string _displayName;
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return _displayName; }
        set { _displayName = value; }
    }
}  

public enum eUserRole : int
{
    [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName = "Super Admin")]
    SuperAdmin = 0,
    [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName = "Phoenix Admin")]
    PhoenixAdmin = 1,
    [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName = "Office Admin")]
    OfficeAdmin = 2,
    [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName = "Report User")]
    ReportUser = 3,
    [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName = "Billing User")]
    BillingUser = 4
}
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: You lose the type of the enum in the dictionary, and replaced it with `int`.

Comment: @FrankJ we can change it easily, if we want to, i updated it

Comment: I think now it is what the OP wants -> +1

Answer (score 0):

Another take on this:

```
class Program
{
    //Example enum
    public enum eFancyEnum
    {
        [Description("Obsolete")]
        Yahoo,
        [Description("I want food")]
        Meow,
        [Description("I want attention")]
        Woof,
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This is how you use it
        Dictionary<eFancyEnum, string> myDictionary = typeof(eFancyEnum).ToDictionary<eFancyEnum>();
    }
}

public static class EnumExtension
{
    //Helper method to get description
    public static string ToDescription<T>(this T en)
    {
         Type type = en.GetType();
         MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());
         if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
         {
            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
               return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
         }
         return en.ToString();
    }

    //The actual extension method that builds your dictionary
    public static Dictionary<T, string> ToDictionary<T>(this Type source) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
         if(!source.IsEnum || typeof(T) != source)
         {
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("BOOM");
         }

         Dictionary<T, string> retVal = new Dictionary<T,string>();

         foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>())
          {
            retVal.Add(item, item.ToDescription());
          }

         return retVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need an enumeration (a static list of known values) that need to have something more than just a mere integer value and a string counterpart, I end up using this [Enumeration Utility class](https://github.com/HeadspringLabs/Enumeration) that essentially gives me java-like enumeration behavior.

So that would be my first option if I were on op's shoes as it would make it really trivial to achieve what he/she wants.

But, assuming this is not an option for op and she/he need to stick with C# enums, I would use a combination of both [ehsan-sajjad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36209063/11099) and [frank-j](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36210201/11099) solutions:

1. Have an extension method to return the description of a given enum
   item, which is pretty much what op had already;
2. Have a static helper method to return a dictionary of items and their respective descriptions for a given enum type.

Here is how I would implement this:

```
public static class EnumUtils
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum enumVal)
    {
        var type = enumVal.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
        var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false);

        return (attributes.Length > 0) ? ((DescriptionAttribute) attributes[0]).Description : null;
    }

    public static Dictionary<TEnum, string> GetItemsWithDescrition<TEnum>()
    {
        var enumType = typeof(TEnum);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("TEnum must be an enum type");
        }

        return Enum
                .GetValues(enumType)
                .Cast<TEnum>()
                .ToDictionary(enumValue => enumValue, enumValue => GetDescription(enumValue as Enum));
    }
}
```

And here is what the usage would look like:

```
public class EnumUtilsTests
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        [Description("Um")]
        One,
        [Description("Dois")]
        Two,
        [Description("Tres")]
        Three,
        NoDescription
    }

    public void Should_get_enum_description()
    {
        MyEnum.One.GetDescription().ShouldBe("Um");
        MyEnum.Two.GetDescription().ShouldBe("Dois");
        MyEnum.Three.GetDescription().ShouldBe("Tres");
        MyEnum.NoDescription.GetDescription().ShouldBe(null);
    }

    public void Should_get_all_enum_values_with_description()
    {
        var response = EnumUtils.GetItemsWithDescrition<MyEnum>();

        response.ShouldContain(x => x.Key == MyEnum.One && x.Value == "Um");
        response.ShouldContain(x => x.Key == MyEnum.Two && x.Value == "Dois");
        response.ShouldContain(x => x.Key == MyEnum.Three && x.Value == "Tres");
        response.ShouldContain(x => x.Key == MyEnum.NoDescription && x.Value == null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
.ToDictionary(k => k, v => v.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)
```

with

```
.Select(t => new { k = t, v = t.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)
.ToDictionary(s => s.k, s => s.v)
```

In your example, the wrong overload of ToDictionary() is being called.