# Cannot get extension method for type Enum

Tags: c#, enums

The problem I'm having is creating the extension method!

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    One, Two, Three, Four
}

public static class EnumExtension
{
   public static bool TestMethod(this TestEnum e)
   {
       return false;
   }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestAll()
{
    var result = TestEnum. ;   //this only gives the values of the enum (One, Two, Three, Four), there is no option to call the extension method
}
```

I hope the comment in the code above really shows the issue - I'm assuming I'm making a massive assumption and getting it very wrong.

I however would rather make this more usable, by allowing any enum to call this functionality. The end goal would be something like

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ConvertToList(this Enum e)
{
     var result = new List<string>();
     foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(e)))    //doesn't like e
     {
         result.Add(name.ToString());
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: `TestEnum` is the type. You can do `TestEnum.One.TestMethod()`, or you can write a  generic `EnumExtensions.TestMethod<TestEnum>() `

Comment: @canton7, thank you for that, but please see my edit. The idea could be to convert any enum into a list of string.

Comment: Again you need to pass the type of enum, not one of its members. You can't do this as an extension method.

Comment: You won't be able to get syntax like `EnumType.ExtensionMethod()`, it cannot be done. You have a couple of options, `EnumType.Value.ExtensionMethod()`, `Extensions.Something<EnumType>()` or `Extensions.Something(typeof(EnumType))`, none of which are significantly better than the existing `Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumType))` method. Basically, you can't do it.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/737940/6299857

Comment: Thank you @PrasadTelkikar, if only it returned a List<string>  (which I can do)

Comment: `Enum.GetName()` returns array of string, you can convert it to `List<string>` by `ToList()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extension method doesn't work on the type directly, but on a value of that type.

So something like

```
TestEnum Val = TestEnum One;
 var b = Val.TestMethod();
```

Comment: So, I can't convert the list of values associated with an `Enum` to a List<string> as an extension method? I'm aware how I can get the code to work without extensions...

Answer (score 1):

If you need list of all enums in `List<string>`, then you can try something like

```
List<string> enumList = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TestEnum)).ToList();
```

This will return list of string containing

```
  //"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"
```

[image]