# Strings Reference riddle

Tags: c#, string, reference

I've encountered with the following code riddle:

```
string a = "S1";
string b = "S2";
a = a+b;
```

What will stay in the memory after this:

1. "S1S2", "S2"
2. "S1", "S1S2"
3. "S1", "S2", "S1S2"

What is your opinion? And why, in my opinion (c)

- string a pointing to `"S1S2"`
- string b pointing to `"S2"`
- And `"S1"` is also in the background even after changing `pointer/reference` of string a

Comment: The first thing you get, is a compiler error for redeclaring `a`.

Comment: Run it and find out.  It took you more time to ask this question than it did to find the answer.

Comment: Riddle? Sounds like something for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Theraot He's not asking to improve it, so CR is out, there's no problem to solve, so CG doesn't make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strings vs classes when both are reference types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739996/strings-vs-classes-when-both-are-reference-types)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think **c** is correct answer, but the reason does not match yours.

You have to be aware of intern pool:

> The common language runtime automatically maintains a table, called
> the intern pool, which contains a single instance of each unique
> literal string constant declared in a program, as well as any unique
> instance of String you add programmatically by calling the `Intern`
> method.
>
> [`String.IsInterned` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And that's why both `S1` and `S2` will be within intern pool even if there is no reference to them.

And why `S1S2` will be in memory is quite obvious - `a` points to that `string`.