# Replace URL in a string

Tags: c#, string

I'm a beginner in C# and I have the following string,

```
string url = "svn1/dev";
```

along with,

```
string urlMod = "ato-svn3-sslv3.of.lan/svn/dev"
```

I want to replace `svn1` in `url` with `"ato-svn3-sslv3.of.lan"`

Comment: Is it always `svn1` you want to replace? Or all characters before the first `/`?

Comment: What have you tried until now? Replacing strings is something google will help you a lot. Did you run into any problems?

Comment: @germi yea its always svn1. Kindly note that I'm having http in first url, and https in the urlMod that is appended to both

Comment: It smells like a string is immutable understanding. THere are plenty of Replace methods on string but you have to assign the result to a variable to get the change string.

Comment: I agree with kat0r, I suggest, being new to C# you learn now how to google the answer to problems like this. It will help you much more than just giving you the answer

Comment: @Kenny, there are a lot of answers that show a lot of people who has high rank, don't understand also that string is immutable

Comment: "don't understand also that string is immutable" @Andre take a  look at the link in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are [**immutable**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274193/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mutable-and-immutable-string-in-c) so you need to assign the return value to a variable:

```
string replacement = "ato-svn3-sslv3.of.lan";
url = url.Replace("svn1", replacement);
```

Comment: you'll end up with `"ato-svn3-sslv3.of.lan/svn/dev/dev"`

Comment: good point @Andrew.  I updated it to use the value he asked to use as a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Although your question still has some inconsistent statements, I believe `String.Replace` is what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

```
url = url.Replace("svn1","ato-svn3-sslv3.of.lan");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string method replace.

```
url = url.Replace("svn1", urlMod)
```

Comment: You'll have to assign that to a variable - `Replace` returns a new `string`, it doesn't alter the one you call it from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
        string url = "svn1/dev";
        string anotherUrl = "ato-svn3-sslv3.of.lan/svn/dev";
        string toBeReplaced = anotherUrl.Split('/')[0];
        url = url.Replace("svn1", toBeReplaced);
```

It uses split method and replace method.