# Loading text in Richtexbox taking long time

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I need your inputs on handling this issue, I am actually getting some 2mb of data(string) which I am storing in file using the method file.readalltext().
and assinging that text to my rich text box.

The windows form is taking almost 1 min to load the data.

To handle this situation should I use thread concept with progress bar, if yes could you please give me some suggestions.
for example:
//this is the method I am using to bind richtextbox.

```
public void bindRTB()
{
this.RTB.Text = File.ReadAllText("some data carrying string");

}
```

Please help me on resolving this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C#, Loading large file into winform richtextbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214687/in-c-loading-large-file-into-winform-richtextbox)

Comment: Filling a RTB with +2MB of text takes less than 1s here. So there is probably something else going on..!