# not allowing to update value for a specific index

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm having problem in assigning a value to the specific index in the string after checking on the same index:
Here below is my code:

"bits" is a string and "dirtybit" is an integer.

```
if (bits.ElementAt(dirtybit).Equals('1'))
      bits[dirtybit] = '0'; //shows red underlined error
```

Error:

> Property or Indexer String.this[int] cannot be assigned to -- is only read

1. Why can I not access the same index (value)?
2. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You can use unsafe code and pointers. But i dont think you really need this. Other way You can use char array and convert it to string when its needed.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary or more likely `bool` array...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeah if 0 and 1 are only values here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274193/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mutable-and-immutable-string-in-c) in C#. You can not change them after you have created them.

You can use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a new string.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx):

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be
>   changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it
>   appear as if you can do this.

Comment: so how can i change any character in a string?