# Why passing string to a method behaves unlike List<object> if they are both reference type?

Tags: c#, ref, out, reference-type

I was reading a code that made me stop at some line:

```
List<object> props = new List<object>();
DoWork(param1, param2, props);
//props.Count grew up
```

I was thinking that changing a variable outside its scope requires passing it as `out` or `ref`, but then I realized that unless the `DoWork` method changes the `props` reference like:

`props = new List<object>();`

the reference will be point to the same location. So there is no need to use `ref` here.

and then I created a method for `string` type:

```
static void ChangeMe(string str)
{
    str = "W77";
}
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "p1";
    ChangeMe(str);
    //str is still "p1"
}
```

If the behavior motivated the List to be changed outside its scope is that it's reference type, why `string` doesn't change if it's not reallocated in the callee method and it's a reference type like `List<object>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is because `string` is an **immutable** type in C# and therefore whenever you "change" it what actually you are doing is creating a new `string` with the new value and referencing to it.

When calling the `ChangeMe` a new reference to the same string is created. Then in the method you are referencing the new reference to a completely new string, which  does not influence the previous string defined in `Main`.

- For the *Why* strings are immutable read:
  [Why .NET String is immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2365272/6400526)
- Also: [What is the difference between a mutable and immutable string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4274193/6400526)

Answer (score 1):

In the function `ChangeMe` you have a local copy of the reference to the object you passed in. When you store something in `str` you basically replace that reference with a new one. Immutability does not play a role here, because you did not actually try to modify the object referenced by `str`. So you now have a new reference stored in `str` which points to a new object created by string constructor when you use string literal `"W77"`. And as you pointed out, you can get that outside the scope of the function by `ref` or `out`.