# Does this code create a temporary string?

Tags: c#

Does this code takes x and changes its contents directly or creates a temporary new string then copy to x?

If the latter is true, I don't understand why we use ref.

```
public static void RemoveSpaces(ref string x)
    {
        x = x.Replace(" ", "");
    }
```

Comment: Considering that strings in c# are immutable, yes, a new instance is created and then the pointer of `x` is assigned to that new instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a mutable and immutable string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274193/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mutable-and-immutable-string-in-c)

Comment: @zaitsman pointer of the new instance is assigned to x or opposite? I mean does x holds the address of the first character of newly formed string?

Comment: Key point to understand is that `x` is not a string but a reference to a string object. And without `ref` that reference would be passed by-value and the effects would not be visble after the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it'll create new string.
Any operation you do on `string` it'll create new string of it, because `string` is immutable type.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `ref` you could change your signature from `void` to `string` and use it like this

```
public static string RemoveSpaces(string x)
{
   return x.Replace(" ","");
}
```

I think it's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use ref, it wont work when you call that function.

```
string y = "Subash Kharel";
RemoveSpaces(y);
Console.Write(y);
```

The result will be  "Subash Kharel" when you don't use ref.

Comment: It is not explained very well, but the guy is right here. If you don't use the ref keyword in the call and **remove it** in the method you can't see the changes with y.