# What is mutation in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mutation

I am reading Joseph Albahari's book "C# 10 in a Nutshell", it talks about "Nondesctructive mutation for anonymous types" but I don't even know what mutation is, on google all I could find was "Mutation testing" or "What is Nondesctructive mutation?" which they always end up in as a side feature to record type. Could someone please break it down to me? Some examples would be much appreciated!

Comment: In this case, "to mutate" just means "to change the state of an object". Do you already understand the [difference between mutable and immutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4274193/87698)? "Nondestructive mutation" is a technique to do something similar to mutation with immutable types.

Comment: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2020/05/csharp-9-non-destructive-mutation/

Comment: @Heinzi so mutation is related to mutability? So, the mutation test is basically "testing if the type of the object is changed" or is it "the value of an object is changed"?

Comment: No, "mutation testing" is something completely different. Mutation testing is called mutation testing because it's about mutating (= changing) **code**. "Nondestructive mutation for anonymous types" is about mutating (= changing) **objects**. In genetics (to give a completely unrelated third example), "mutation" refers to changes in the **genome**. That's the beauty of the English language: Words are meaningless without context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To mutate** (in the sense used in "nondesctructive mutation for anonymous types") just means **to change the state of an object**. Here is a simple example:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");

// We mutate the object referenced by sb, so that it contains
// "Hello!" rather than "Hello".
sb.Append("!")

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());   // prints Hello!
```

`StringBuilder` is a *mutable* class. Other classes, such as `String`, are **immutable**:

```
var s = "Hello";

// The following expression returns a *new* string "hello",
// but does not mutate the original string itself.
s.ToLower();

Console.WriteLine(s);   // still prints Hello
```

So, what do we do if we want to mutate the contents of an immutable class, for example, to lowercase the contents of a string? We *create a new object* that contains the modified version. This is what `string.ToLower` does:

```
var s1 = "Hello";
var s2 = s1.ToLower();

Console.WriteLine(s1);   // prints Hello
Console.WriteLine(s2);   // prints hello
```

This is called **non-destructive mutation**: The original string `s1` still exists, it has not been destroyed. On the other hand, `sb.Append("!")` in the very first example was *destructive*: The version of `sb` containing `Hello` (without exclamation mark) is no longer accessible.

*(Obviously, you can re-use the same variable name when lowercasing a string, e.g. `s = s.ToLower()`. But that does not change the fact that `ToLower` creates a new object rather than modifying the old one in-place. `s = ...` ensures that the variable `s` points to the new object afterwards.)*

---

So, what does this have to do with anonymous types? Anonymous types in C# are immutable:

```
var myObject = new { A = 1, B = 2 };

myObject.B = 3;   // <- yields a compile-time error
```

C#9 introduced the `with` keyword, which allows you to *create a new object* which is an exact copy of the original object, except for the values you want to change:

```
var o1 = new { A = 1, B = 2 };
var o2 = o1 with { B = 3 };
    
// o1: A = 1, B = 2
// o2: A = 1, B = 3
```