# Foreach copy and text

Tags: c#, foreach

My code:

```
List<string> fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList();
foreach (string file in fileList)
{
    File.Copy(file, biosAllDir + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(file), true);
    string fileWithoutPath = Path.GetFileName(file);
    outputTextbox.Text = $"Copied: {fileWithoutPath}" + Environment.Newline; 
}
```

This foreach loop copies all the files in the list fine but when it comes to adding text to the outputTextbox it just adds one line (the last one) and not any other, do you know why?

Thanks

Comment: You're replacing the content of the textbox each time, not appending to it (i.e. `=` instead of `+=`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every iteration, you are just assigning the result to your textbox. To add them up - you need to use `+=` instead of `=`

```
outputTextbox.Text += $"Copied: {fileWithoutPath}" + Environment.Newline;
```

But will be better to use [`StringBuilder`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder) for this case.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<string> fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList();
foreach (string file in fileList)
{
    File.Copy(file, biosAllDir + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(file), true);
    string fileWithoutPath = Path.GetFileName(file);
    sb.AppendLine($"Copied: {fileWithoutPath}");
}

outputTextbox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

References: **[StringBuilder](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder)**, **[When to use StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825781/when-to-use-stringbuilder)**

Comment: Why is it better in this case to use `StringBuilder`?. Feels to me (admittedly a feeling, haven't looked at the sourcecode for `StringBuilder`) this is one of the cases where it either doesn't matter or the `StringBuilder` will be slower due to added management around it. So I' interested in what it does that makes it better.

Comment: @Knoop at the bottom, I've added [When to use StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825781/when-to-use-stringbuilder) link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/530014/10608418. This is where I ended up, states specifically that if you're using the intermediate result (like this case) `StringBuilder` is not going to help you...

Comment: @Knoop This one is this case: _"Definitely use StringBuilder when you're concatenating in a non-trivial loop - especially if you don't know for sure (at compile time) how many iterations you'll make through the loop. For example, reading a file a character at a time, building up a string as you go using the += operator is potentially performance suicide."_

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess it's way too hot here, for some reason I thought the `outputTextbox.Text = sb.ToString()` was inside the loop. You're absolutely right this is a case where `StringBuilder` shines, my aplogies.

Comment: @Knoop It's ok, have a nice day)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are just assigning `$"Copied: {fileWithoutPath}" + Environment.Newline;` to `outputTextbox.Text` variable in each foreach loop iteration. Instead of assignment, you need to append that string to previously stored value. You can do it using [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8)

You can use `StringBuilder` to store all file paths and assign string from string builder out of `foreach` loop to `outputTextbox.Text`

You can try below code

```
List<string> fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string file in fileList)
{
    string fileWithoutPath = Path.GetFileName(file); // Refactored to remove duplicate code.
    File.Copy(file, biosAllDir + @"\" + fileWithoutPath, true);
    sb.AppendLine($"Copied: {fileWithoutPath}");
}

outputTextbox.Text = sb.ToString();
```