# Why does ToString() method of Exception class in .Net not use a StringBuilder to build the string?

Tags: c#, string, tostring, stringbuilder

I would expect the code below (from the Exception class in .Net framework) to use a StringBuilder to build a string and then return a builder.ToString() instead of using the "+" operator on the existing string, which ends up creating a new string everytime.

I expect folks writing .Net source code to follow the best practices where ever possible, therefore I want to double check if this is still somehow optimal

```
private String ToString(bool needFileLineInfo, bool needMessage) {
    String message = (needMessage ? Message : null);
    String s;
    if (message == null || message.Length <= 0) {
        s = GetClassName();
    }
    else {
        s = GetClassName() + ": " + message;
    }

    if (_innerException!=null) {
        s = s + " ---> " + _innerException.ToString(needFileLineInfo, needMessage) 
              + Environment.NewLine 
              + "   "
              + Environment.GetResourceString("Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack");

    }

    string stackTrace = GetStackTrace(needFileLineInfo);
    if (stackTrace != null)
    {
        s += Environment.NewLine + stackTrace;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Not a bug. At worst a minor inefficiency, but chances are the compiler is going to optimise it for you anyway.

Comment: Nobody will be able to provide a definitive answer to this, as it's all speculation.  My guess: since it's an exception it should only happen in exceptional cases.  If it's happening, you're pretty much boned anyway.

Comment: Maybe it's faster this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612797/string-concatenation-vs-string-builder-performance

Comment: Somewhat speculative, but I would suggest you think about *when* an exception is being created. StringBuilder would allocate an initial buffer, which won't always be possible depending on what sort of meltdown the application is having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to know for sure why the author of the code chose this implementation, without asking the author of the code.

That said, it's worth keeping in mind that the general guidance to prefer `StringBuilder` over simple `string` concatenation applies mainly to looping scenarios where you have arbitrarily large iteration counts.

In the example above, the main part of the method should wind up calling the `Concat()` method, which should do a better job of creating a single new `string` object from the inputs than appending each part iteratively using `StringBuilder`. To introduce `StringBuilder` for the other concatenation, especially when they are not always going to happen (since they are conditional), could very well be less optimal in the common scenarios.

See e.g. [String concatenation vs String Builder. Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1612835), where this difference is specifically called out.

Comment: yes, that makes sense