# which one is provide faster string operation : StringBuilder vs. String

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder)

i know .NET Strings are immutable which is the reason why a new string object is created every time we alter it (insert, append, remove, etc.).

That sounds reasonable, so why do we still use the .NET String class functions and not the faster StringBuilder?

Comment: Regarding the last part of your question, `strings`, as you say, are immutable. `StringBuilders` aren't (that's their primary asset). Both types allow you to work with characters, but they don't have the same semantics at all, and one cannot completely replace the other.

Comment: This [String vs StringBuilder question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder) has 32 votes and 24 answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is faster for repeated (non-compile-time) concatenations in a loop.

For ordinary string operations, they perform equivalently.

In particular, `a + b + c` is compiled as `String.Concat(a, b, c)`, which allocates a single buffer and is as fast or faster than a string builder.
`StringBuilder` is only faster than *multiple* separate `Concat`s, since each `Concat` will need to make a new buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: it's easier, and performance is rarely an issue. Maintainability is much more important unless specifically otherwise required by the project.

Which is easier to you? This:

```
public override string ToString() {
    return this.LastName + ", " + this.FirstName;
}
```

or this?

```
public override string ToString() {
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(this.LastName);
    sb.Append(", ");
    sb.Append(this.FirstName);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Admittedly, you'd probably use `var` and `using System.Text;`, but it's still much more complicated and much less readable. And `StringBuilder` is mostly for concatenation in some form of loop, since otherwise the operations can be optimized, so you rarely need to use them.

Comment: As an alternative, return String.Format("{0}, {1}", Lastname, Firstname); which creates one string instead of 2 (of which one is thrown away right away)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Sure, that too :)

Comment: Actually, in this case the first method will probably perform better too. StringBuilder is useful when you *can't* express the whole concatenation in a single expression.

Comment: Or of course, sb.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}", Lastname, Firstname);

Comment: You can also chain the sb calls, since the sb operations return sb. `sb.Append(this.LastName).Append(", ").Append(this.FirstName);

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson `LastName + ", " + FirstName` is compiled as `string.Concat(LastName, ", ", FirstName)` so it doesn't actually create an extra string.  `string.Format()`, on the other hand, has a lot of overhead that `string.Concat()` doesn't.  So `LastName + ", " + FirstName` really is more efficient.

Comment: @phoog Cool, I had to idlasm to confirm that, you learn something new every day :) @ minitech Definitely no downvote from me.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson There are some good pieces about this online.  Jon Skeet has a very good one, though it is slightly out of date as it discusses some implementation details of StringBuilder, and that implementation changed quite a bit in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the MSDN articles for both [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) and [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) there are several methods on `String` that are not on `StringBuilder`.  `Trim`, `IndexOf`, `Pad[Left|Right]`, `ToUpper`, and `ToLower` just to name a few.  On top of that as minitech pointed out, `StringBuilder` is a pain to work with.  `StringBuilder` is great if you have a lot of string manipulations to do.  But for the simple stuff, `String` works just fine.