# Comparing two HashSets/Lists of Data with same hashcodes and similar data

Tags: c#, asp.net, binaryfiles, arcgis

I am writing software that compares differences between two sets of binary data. The binary data contains coordinates, and it also reads from a DBF file to get attribute information about each object. My software indicates whether an object has moved, had it's attributes changed, had an object removed/added.

My custom object hashcode is generated based on a list of coordinates within each instance. **There is also a datarow in each object**. When I initially try to find "imperfect records"(basically any objects where there isn't a match based on coordinates and the datarow), it takes the datarow into consideration, and I can use a HashSet since the datarow makes it unique enough.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        if (considerAttrs)
        {
            return (value.GetHashCode() + dbString.GetHashCode());
        }
        else
        {
            return value.GetHashCode();
        }

    }
```

**Where I am:**

The software at this moment returns objects without a perfect match (no exact match for coordinates and attributes). This data is correct (At least I hope)

origUnfoundCount: 114
modUnfoundCount: 223

It can't find 114 in the original because 113 have modified attributes, and 1 has been moved. It can't find 223 in the modified because there are 113 modified attributes, 1 has been moved, and 109 have been added.

**Where I'm stuck:**

The software works with smaller data (couple hundred in each list) beautifully

I changed the considerAttrs in each object to false and used a List instead of a HashSet. The speed penalty is drastic, to the point of my application only being good for comparing small differences between data.

**I need to use a List however since you can't have duplicates in a hashset, but Lists are just way to slow. A dictionary can't be used since the key has to be unique**

I need a new approach, my logic below should give you the general gist of what I need it to do.

My current comparison code

```
    //ignored modified records
    HashSet<int> ignoredRecNo = new HashSet<int>();
    //ignoring moved records
    HashSet<String> ignoredDBstrings = new HashSet<string>();

    HashSet<String> columnNames = new HashSet<string>();
    HashSet<int> modModdedRNs = new HashSet<int>();
    columnNames = (HashSet<String>)HttpContext.Current.Session["columnNames"];

    List<PolyLineZ> originalNFs = new List<PolyLineZ>();
    List<PolyLineZ> modifiedNFs = new List<PolyLineZ>();

    List<PolyLineZ> removedList = new List<PolyLineZ>();
    List<PolyLineZ> movedList = new List<PolyLineZ>();
    List<PolyLineZ> modifiedList = new List<PolyLineZ>();
    List<PolyLineZ> modifiedMatchList = new List<PolyLineZ>();

    List<PolyLineZ> movedOrDeleted = new List<PolyLineZ>();

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["origNFList"] != null)
    {
        origPolyLineZNFList = (HashSet<PolyLineZ>)HttpContext.Current.Session["origNFList"];
    }

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["modNFList"] != null)
    {
        modPolyLineZNFList = (HashSet<PolyLineZ>)HttpContext.Current.Session["modNFList"];
    }


    //----------Generate Lists of string for each row---------------//
    foreach (PolyLineZ polyLineZ in origPolyLineZNFList)
    {
        origDBStrings.Add(polyLineZ.dbString);
        PolyLineZ temp = new PolyLineZ();
        temp = polyLineZ;
        temp.considerAttrs = false;
        originalNFs.Add(temp);
    }

    foreach (PolyLineZ polyLineZ in modPolyLineZNFList)
    {
        modDBStrings.Add(polyLineZ.dbString);
        PolyLineZ temp = new PolyLineZ();
        temp = polyLineZ;
        temp.considerAttrs = false;
        modifiedNFs.Add(temp);
    }


    foreach (PolyLineZ modpolyLineZ in modifiedNFs)
    {
        bool foundAmatch = false;
        foreach (PolyLineZ origPolyLineZ in originalNFs)
        {
            if (origPolyLineZ.Equals(modpolyLineZ))
            {
                if (!modDBStrings.Contains(origPolyLineZ.dbString))
                {
                    //database modifications are in here                        
                    modModdedRNs.Add(origPolyLineZ.RecordNumber);
                    foundAmatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    foreach (PolyLineZ polyLineZ in originalNFs)
    {
        bool foundAmatch = false;
        foreach (PolyLineZ modpolyLineZ in modifiedNFs)
        {
            if (foundAmatch)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (modpolyLineZ.Equals(polyLineZ))
            {
                if (!origDBStrings.Contains(modpolyLineZ.dbString))
                {

                    foundAmatch = true;
                    //database modifications are in here                            
                    ignoredRecNo.Add(modpolyLineZ.RecordNumber);
                    ignoredDBstrings.Add(modpolyLineZ.dbString);
                    modifiedList.Add(polyLineZ);
                    modifiedMatchList.Add(modpolyLineZ);
                    break;

                } // end db string comparison

            } //end shape equals if

        } //end modNF loop

        if (!foundAmatch)
        {
            movedOrDeleted.Add(polyLineZ);
            ignoredDBstrings.Add(polyLineZ.dbString);
            ignoredRecNo.Add(polyLineZ.RecordNumber);
        }

    } //end origNF loop


    result += "movedDeletedCount: " + movedOrDeleted.Count + "<br/>";
    foreach (PolyLineZ polylineZ in movedOrDeleted)
    {

        if (!modDBStrings.Contains(polylineZ.dbString))
        {
                removedList.Add(polylineZ);
        }
        else
        {

                movedList.Add(polylineZ);   
        }
    }

    /*************************** ITERATE DATABASE CHANGES***********************************/
    for(int i=0; i < modifiedList.Count;i++)
    {
        if (modModdedRNs.Contains(modifiedList[i].RecordNumber))
        {
            if (modifiedAttrs < 1001)
            {
                //database modifications are in here                            
                ignoredRecNo.Add(modifiedMatchList[i].RecordNumber);
                ignoredDBstrings.Add(modifiedMatchList[i].dbString);
                modifiedAttrs++;
                modifiedResults += "<div class='turnBlue'>";
                //show where the change was made at
                modifiedResults += "Change Detected at original FID# " + (modifiedList[i].RecordNumber - 1) + " and modified FID#";
                HashSet<String> mismatchedColumns = new HashSet<String>();
                modifiedResults += (modifiedMatchList[i].RecordNumber - 1);
                modifiedResults += "</div>"; //end turnblue div
                DataRow origRow = modifiedList[i].datarow;
                DataRow modRow = modifiedMatchList[i].datarow;
                foreach (String columnName in columnNames)
                {
                    String origRowValue = "" + origRow.Field<Object>(columnName);
                    String modRowValue = "" + modRow.Field<Object>(columnName);
                    if (!modRowValue.Equals(origRowValue))
                    {
                        mismatchedColumns.Add(columnName);

                    }
                }
                foreach (String mismatchedColumn in mismatchedColumns)
                {

                    //grab original attr value
                    String origMismatchedRowValue = "" + origRow.Field<Object>(mismatchedColumn);
                    //grab the modified value
                    String modMismatchedRowValue = "" + modRow.Field<Object>(mismatchedColumn);
                    //generate a heading, letting the user know about the situation
                    modifiedResults += "<div class='turnBlue'>Value at Column: &nbsp;<b>" + mismatchedColumn + "</b> has been modified<br/>";
                    modifiedResults += "<div class='pushLeft'>Original value: &nbsp;<b>" + origMismatchedRowValue + "</b><br/></div>";
                    modifiedResults += "<div class='pushLeft'>Modified value: &nbsp;<b>" + modMismatchedRowValue + "</b><br/></div>";
                    modifiedResults += "</div>"; //end modified div 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                modifiedAttrs++;
            }


        }
        else
        {
            if (removed < 1001)
            {
                //iterate removed data here
                removed++;
            }
            else
            {
                removed++;
            }

        }
    }
    //****************************this determines which ones have been added ***************************/

    foreach (PolyLineZ modpolyLineZ in modifiedNFs)
    {
        if (!ignoredRecNo.Contains(modpolyLineZ.RecordNumber) && (!ignoredDBstrings.Contains(modpolyLineZ.dbString)))
        {
            //iterate added data here
        }

    }

    foreach (PolyLineZ polylineZ in removedList)
    {
        //iterate removed data here
    }
    foreach (PolyLineZ polylineZ in movedList)
    {
        //iterate  moved data here

    }

    result += "<div id='addedJump'></div>" + addedResult;
    result += "<div id='moddedJump'></div>" + modifiedResults;
    result += "<div id='removedJump'></div>" + removedResults;
    result += "<div id='movedJump'></div>" + movedResults;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from appending all data onto a single string to using a stringbuilder...

It took my program down from 30 minutes to detect 3,200 removed records down to seven seconds flat.

See this question for more information:

[String vs. StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder)