# string and StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I have written two concept for adding or initializing two string 
just want to know in both concept final str1 reference will be change from starting ?

1. string str1="A";
         str1="B";
2. string srt1="A"+"B";

Please answer me in concept of stringBuilder

thanks

Comment: Both are not same. Did you mean `str1 += "B"` ?

Comment: This question is *extremely* unclear. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: When you use `+` between two strings, they are concatenated at compile time.

Comment: No I means same what I have written ....if I do str1="B" means this will write in other memory location right ?

Comment: Your `1.` will result in `str1 == "B"`, while `2.` will result in `str1 == "AB"`

Comment: I am asking in concept of stringBuilder ...both are doing same job means adding 2 character changing address ?

Answer (score 2):

strings are immutable, its recommended to avoid direct string concatenation frequently or in a large loop. In your case, impact of performance is nil. look at - [String vs. StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder)