# C# Replace all characters in string with X except spaces

Tags: c#, string, replace, character

I'm making a hangman game in C#, and it needs to show the player the sentence, but with ALL characters as an "X", EXCEPT a space with a space. So if the sentence is "I'm a person" it would be "XXX X XXXXXX". I have found a way to do this when EVERY character replaces with "X", but the problem is that, spaces is also replaced with X.

The code:

```
string WrVS = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < Words[randomVal].Length; i++)
{
    WrVS += "X";
}
RWordCensored.Text = WrVS;
```

(randomVal is the random number that selects a random sentence from a list),
(RWordCensored is a richTextBox that should show the sentence in the format I said.

I haven't found an answer on Google to my question.

/Viktor

Comment: "I'm a person" is three words with a space between each word.

Comment: `I haven't found an answer on Google to my question.` Is this the problem of new generation? You don't have to find an answer that does **exactly** what you want. You should adopt them to your problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant "sentence" and not "word". And by "I haven't found an answer on Google to my question" I didn't mean just that I didn't found an answer to just my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably check to see what the character is that you're replacing before replacing it.

```
string WrVS = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < Words[randomVal].Length; i++)
{
    char ch = Words[randomVal][i];
    WrVS += ch == ' ' ? ' ' : 'X';
}
RWordCensored.Text = WrVS;
```

Alternatively, you could use LINQ:

```
RWordCensored.Text = new string(
    (from ch in Words[randomVal]
     select ch => ch == ' ' ? ' ' : 'X').ToArray());
```

(or use the other format, as shown in `Habib`'s answer.)

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
var res=new Regex("\\S").Replace("I am a person","X");
//res will be X XX X XXXXXX
```

Comment: yours i liked the best , works like a charm. no need for fancy linq or string builders..

Comment: What is `"\\S"`?

Answer (score 6):

Could be done using REGEX *(I suppose)* , but here is LINQ option.

```
string str = "I'm a person";
string replacedString = new String(str.Select(r => r == ' ' ? ' ' : 'X').ToArray());
```

And you will get back `replacedString = "XXX X XXXXXX"`

Answer (score 1):

Add this check

```
if(Words[randomVal][i] != " ") //If the character is NOT a whitespace
{
    WrVS += "X";
}
else WrVS += " "; //If the character IS a white space
```

Comment: This won't add any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether the char is space you could use [Char.IsWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
StringBuilder WrVS = new StringBuilder(Words.Length);

foreach(var ch in Words)
{
   ch = Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch) ? ch : 'X';
   wrVs.Append(ch)
}

RWordCensored.Text = WrVS.ToString();
```

Also, when you are processing the string in such a manner you should use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class - [String vs. StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder)

Comment: I doubt that this hangman-esque game requires the efficiency of a `StringBuilder`, but it's best to develop good habits.