# Ignore null values in reader

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

Hi how can I ignore null values in a reader c# in my statement =>

```
 LegalDesc = reader["legal1"].ToString() + ' ' + 
             reader["legal2"].ToString() + ' ' + 
             reader["legal3"].ToString();
```

Scenario: if legal2 is a null value the resulting string would be

```
 legalDesc = legal1 + ' ' + legal3
```

How could apply iif used in VB?

Comment: How about `reader["legal2"] ?? " "`?

Comment: How about `reader.IsDbNull`?

Comment: would you re-phrase my script...thanks

Comment: LegalDesc = (reader["legal1"] ?? "") + " " + 
             (reader["legal2"] ?? "") + " " + 
             (reader["legal3"] ?? ""); This is what Soner meant.

Comment: 'string' is not a valid syntax for string literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a collection and `String.Join`:

```
List<string> legals = new List<string>();
if(!reader.IsDbNull(reader.GetOrdinal("legal1")))
    legals.Add(reader["legal1"].ToString());
if(!reader.IsDbNull(reader.GetOrdinal("legal2")))
    legals.Add(reader["legal2"].ToString());
if(!reader.IsDbNull(reader.GetOrdinal("legal3")))
    legals.Add(reader["legal3"].ToString());
LegalDesc = string.Join(" ", legals);
```

Of course you could also make the code more elegant by using a custom extension method:

```
public static string SafeGetString(this SqlDataReader reader, int colIndex)
{
   if(!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
       return reader.GetString(colIndex);
   else 
       return string.Empty;
}
```

Now you can use:

```
string[] legals = { reader.SafeGetString(0), reader.SafeGetString(1), reader.SafeGetString(2) };
LegalDesc = string.Join(" ", legals.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

This presumes that it's actually a `string` column and the column ordinal positions  are from 0 to 2. If that's not the case use above shown `reader.GetOrdinal` approach to detect them.

Comment: you can shorten the code with a for loop. reader["legal" + i]

Comment: I am receiving an error for the .isdbnull is highlighted red in VS. The data is coming from excel sheet calling the class to load inside the Grid...

Comment: @RezoMegrelidze:  but that will fail as soon as OP changes the column names or don't want to include all but only specific numbers.

Comment: @Jake: maybe because you haven't noticed that i've already fixed a bug. `reader.IsDbNull` takes an int for the ordinal position of the column(so the index).

Comment: public static string SafeGetString(this SqlDataReader reader, int colIndex)
{
   if(!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
       return reader.GetString(colIndex);
   else 
       return string.Empty;
}

Comment: @Jake: since that is an extension method i guess that you have added the code in a `static class` that is accessible from the code where you use it?!

Comment: @Jake: what code are you showing there? It's not related to mine.

Comment: public UserViewModel(DataTableReader reader)
        {
           RollNumber = reader["roll_nt"].ToString();
           Owners = reader["owner_2"].ToString();
          
                LegalDesc = reader["legal1"].ToString() + ' ' + reader["legal3"].ToString() + ' ' + reader["legal3"].ToString();
         }
    }

Comment: The data is coming from excel file calling this script to view inside the Grid...

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple extension method:

```
public static string ValueOrEmpty(this object source) 
{
     return source == null ? string.Empty : source.ToString();
}

var values = new[] { reader["legal1"],reader["legal2"],reader["legal3"] };
LegalDesc = string.Join(" ", 
                        values.Select(x => x.ValueOrEmpty())
                              .Where(x => x != string.Empty));
```

Answer (score 0):

First

**Do Not** do string concatenation like that, every time you concatenate, it creates a new instance of string because string is `Immutable`. There is a C# class that handles appends and it's `StringBuilder`

So try implementing it like this

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(reader["legal1"])
    .Append(" ")
    .Append(reader["legal2"])
    .Append(" ")
    .Append(reader["legal3"]);
Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

This way, you don't even need to check if it's null.

Comment: True stringbuilder is the way to go, but if you are only ever going to concatenate three pieces of string, the improvement is minuscule to the point that in a lot of places it could be ignored. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder

Comment: @Shekhar true also, but the added benefit here is the null checking being removed.

Comment: I disagree on StringBuilder usage for short things like this (string.Concat is better) and in any case we are talking of micro-optimizations that have no sense here, however this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just to want rephrase my problem...

how can view a value to a LegalDesc = reader["legal1"].ToString() if legal1 is null?

I am viewing my result in a grid and so the grid shows NULL in the cell. The result should be a blank space instead of NULL....
in VB net I could use the IIf function if null then blank space...