# What is the difference bewteen the string and string builder in c#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Is there a significant difference between `String` and `StringBuilder` in C# and when would you use one over the other?

Example:

Using String `string stringVal = "Hello World!"`

or we can do it using StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sbMyValue = new StringBuilder("");
sbMyValue.Append("Hello World");
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` allows more efficient concatenation of strings.  If you concatenate multiple individual strings you wind up making lots of copies of the strings involved (as they are immutable in C#), whereas with `StringBuilder` only one copy is made.   In your example above there is practically no difference, and there might be a little more overhead with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: its a performance thing.  it is probably best said here.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder

Comment: `Is there a significant difference between String and StringBuilder in C#` Yes absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is mutable which gives better performance when you need to manipulate content multiple times.

In case of `string`, it has to create instances multiple times because string is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

this article explains the difference between the two neatly: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6771/String-Vs-StringBuilder-C)
to summarize :
String

`String` is immutable, Immutable means if you create string object then you cannot modify it and It always create new object of string type in memory.
Stringbuilder

`StringBuilder` is mutable, means if create string builder object then you can perform any operation like insert, replace or append without creating new instance for every time.it will update string at one place in memory doesnt create new space in memory.
**So, String builder saves a lot of memory when it comes to concatenation.**

Comment: This should be a comment, not a link only answer.

Comment: yeah.I was about to edit it .Modified.