# Changing String into altCase

Tags: java, string, char

I am trying to write code which will change given string into alt case.

```
"hello" ---> "HeLlO"
"legend of zelda" ---> "LeGeNd oF ZeLdA"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public String altCase(String text) {
    String replace = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            replace = text.replace(Character.toString(text.charAt(i)),
                    Character.toString(text.charAt(i)).toLowerCase());
        } else {
            replace = text.replace(Character.toString(text.charAt(i)),
                    Character.toString(text.charAt(i)).toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    return replace;
}
```

`replace` turns into `text` and nothing else changes.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the code by:

- turn everything to lowercase
- flip every other letter to uppercase
- use a `StringBuilder` to make the code simpler

Then it's just a few lines, like this:

```
public static String altCase(String text){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(text.toLowerCase());
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i+= 2)
        result.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(i)));
    return result.toString();
}
```

Note how I don't convert the character to a String then call `toUpperCase()`, I call the utility method `Character.toUpperCase()` on the character directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public String altCase(String text)
{
    String replace = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            replace += Character.toString(text.charAt(i)).toLowerCase());
        }
        else
        {
            replace += Character.toString(text.charAt(i)).toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    return replace;
}
```

Just append either the lower case or upper case character to the existing string. I'd also have a look at [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) as well. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder)

Comment: I would also suggest using the StringBuilder for better performance (especially if you may have a large String) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html +1

Comment: An explanation on why his attempt fails would be worth extra bonus points