# writing table data with 16k rows to file is timing out

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a feature on my website where an admin can download the contents of a table. The table has about 16ks and only 8 columns.

Here is my C# code

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {

            string query = "SELECT * from wp_portal_users";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
            {

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();

                MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                if (sdr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("sysproID");
                    dt.Columns.Add("password");
                    dt.Columns.Add("username");
                    dt.Columns.Add("update_time", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("tempPasswordValidity");
                    dt.Columns.Add("tempPassword");
                    dt.Columns.Add("last_login");
                    dt.Columns.Add("login_count");
                    dt.Rows.Add("Syspro ID", "Password", "Username", "Last Updated", "Temp Password Validity", "Temp Password", "Last Login", "Login Count");
                    DataRow dr = null;

                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["sysproID"] = sdr["sysproID"].ToString();
                        dr["password"] = sdr["password"].ToString();
                        dr["username"] = sdr["username"].ToString();
                        dr["update_time"] = sdr["update_time"].ToString();
                        dr["tempPasswordValidity"] = sdr["tempPasswordValidity"].ToString();
                        dr["tempPassword"] = sdr["tempPassword"].ToString();
                        dr["last_login"] = sdr["last_login"].ToString();
                        dr["login_count"] = sdr["login_count"].ToString();
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }

                string csv = string.Empty;

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        //Add the Data rows.
                        csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                    }

                    //Add new line.
                    csv += "\r\n";
                }

                //Download the CSV file.
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PortalUsers.csv");
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                Response.Output.Write(csv);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }

        }
```

When this runs on a table with only a few rows it works well. With 16k rows it times out. What can i change to correct this performance issue?

Comment: I'd recommend not building the file in memory, especially not [without using the `StringBuilder` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder). Perhaps you could directly serve it to the output stream?

Answer (score 1):

You should not build a datatable in memory just to iterate though the rows (and then throw it away). 
Datatables are rather slow to build manually.

Instead use your MySqlDataReader to add the column strings to your variable.

Something like this:

```
            if (sdr.HasRows == true)
            {
                string csv = string.Empty;

                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    csv += sdr["sysproID"].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                    // add other columns

                    csv += "\r\n";
                }
            }
            //Download the CSV file.
```

**Edit**:

As @John mentioned in comment, you should use a StringBuilder to build the csv:

```
            if (sdr.HasRows == true)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append(sdr["sysproID"].ToString().Replace(",", ";"));
                    sb.Append(";");
                    // add other columns

                    sb.AppendLine();
                }
            }
            //Download the CSV file.
```

Comment: Perhaps you should address the issue of string concatenation in your answer, too?

Comment: You're right, he should use a stringbuilder to concenate strings.