# change value by reference when using an extension method

Tags: c#

I want to create an error message string. It should contain multiple hints to fix the errors.

First I created something like this

```
string errorMessage = string.Empty;

if (1 == 1)
    errorMessage += "- hint 1\n";

if (2 == 2)
    errorMessage += "- hint 2\n";

if (3 == 3)
    errorMessage += "- hint 3";

// do something with errorMessage
```

And I thought about cleaning it up. I created an extension method

```
public static void AppendIf(this string s, bool condition, string txtToAppend)
{
    if (condition)
        s += txtToAppend;
}
```

And call it within my class

```
string errorMessage = string.Empty;

errorMessage.AppendIf(1 == 1, "- hint 1\n");
errorMessage.AppendIf(2 == 2, "- hint 2\n");
errorMessage.AppendIf(3 == 3, "- hint 3");

// do something with errorMessage
```

But `errorMessage` stays empty. I thought `this` acts like the `ref` keyword so what is wrong with my extension method?

Comment: Well, `this` does not act like the `ref` keyword... that's basically all there is to it. `string` is an immutable object; slapping on an extension method does not make it mutable. You want a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: `if (1 == 1)`? What's the point?

Comment: you probably want to return a new string from your extension method

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, I will have a look.

Comment: @SeM just an example

Comment: If I remember correctly, ref extension methods available in `c#7.2+`, but do you really need to do that way?

Comment: @SeM: `ref` extension methods require value types, which `string` is not.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes I know, I was about to add that to my comment. Also you can have generic type constrained to struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not use `this ref` modifier, please check [compiler feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/165).

However you can get the same result by using the `StringBuilder` type:

```
public static void AppendIf(this StringBuilder s, bool condition, string txtToAppend)
{
    if (condition)
        s.Append(txtToAppend);
}
```

So, your code will be:

```
string errorMessage = new StringBuilder();

errorMessage.AppendIf(1 == 1, "- hint 1\n");
errorMessage.AppendIf(2 == 2, "- hint 2\n");
errorMessage.AppendIf(3 == 3, "- hint 3");
```

NB: please avoid executing code like `str += anotherStr;` inside the loop, because this method has O(N^2) complexity, where N is count of chars. Please check details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder).

Answer (score 3):

`string` is immutable, which means that it creates a new string every time you append to it, so it is impossible.

However, you can use `StringBuilder` to achieve it:

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static StringBuilder AppendLineIf(this StringBuilder builder, bool condition, string line)
    {
        // validate arguments
        if (condition) 
            builder.AppendLine(line);
        return builder;            
    }

    public static StringBuilder AppendIf(this StringBuilder builder, bool condition, string line)
    {
        // validate arguments
        if (condition) 
            builder.Append(line);
        return builder;            
    }
}

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLineIf(1 == 1, "- hint 1");
builder.AppendLineIf(2 == 2, "- hint 2");
builder.AppendLineIf(3 == 3, "- hint 3");

string result = builder.ToString();
// do something with result
```

You can also chain these calls, if it looks better for you:

```
string result = new StringBuilder()
    .AppendLineIf(1 == 1, "- hint 1")
    .AppendLineIf(2 == 2, "- hint 2")
    .AppendLineIf(3 == 3, "- hint 3")
    .ToString();
```

Comment: Like this solution more than the other one because of returning StringBuilder instead of void from your extension methods.